# Inserting links in text

Tags: support, questions, hyperlinks

I dont know how can i put some hyperlinks in text? For example if I want to write down "You can use minecraft wiki to see" How can I make "minecraft wiki" become a hyperlink?

Comment: I have seen very similar sentence with that hyperlink but didn`t realyze how to insert them, even though i read raw text when i pressed edit.

Answer (score 1):

[image]